# When i delete product in product table then productIndex not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, activeadmin, acts-as-paranoid, chewy-gem

When i delete product in product table then productIndex not update.

`My Query:`

Product.friendly.where(slug: params[:id]).first.destroy_fully!

`Model:`

class Product < ApplicationRecord

acts_as_paranoid #for soft Delete

extend FriendlyId #slug

friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

update_index('products#product') { self }

end

`Chewy library:`

define_type Product.includes(:brand, product_images_attachments: :blob) do
field :id
field :name
field :name
field :slug
end
end

`GemFile`

gem 'activeadmin'

gem 'acts_as_paranoid'

## gem 'email_validator'

gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.4.0'

gem 'chewy', git: 'https://github.com/abdullah5514/chewy.git'

gem 'active_model_serializers'

Comment: Can you explain what happens exactly?  Like the  steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: When i delete product Active record   then  chewy not  remove that record in Chewy Tables.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that issue. This is an issue with the `acts_as_paranoid` gem.

Just, I added this into your chewy initializer, i.e. config/initializers/chewy.rb:

Chewy.use_after_commit_callbacks = false